# How do I create a callback function for when the fading function is done?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I'm fading out `img2` in the `fadeOutEffect` function I created within 2.5 seconds(0.05x50),

now here is the problem; I want to `console.log('fadeOut done')` *just exactly when the `img2` has finished fading out*, which I guess I should be creating a `callback` function for `fadeOutEffect` function, or maybe when I'm calling this function, giving it a last argument as a `callback` function (?), which is what I already tried but didn't work out? I know this would be so easy by using jQuery, but I want to use pure JavaScript for this approach.

I literally have no idea for how I should make this happen, any suggestions would be welcome!

```js
let _sliderBox = document.getElementsByClassName('fadeSlider')[0];
    let img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF';
    _sliderBox.appendChild(img1);
    let img2 = new Image();
    img2.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/FF0000';
    _sliderBox.appendChild(img2);
    function fadeOutEffect(fadeTarget, interval) {
        let fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
            if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity){
                fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
            }
            if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0){
                fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.05;
            } else {
                clearInterval(fadeEffect);
            }
        }, interval)
    }
    fadeOutEffect(document.querySelector( `.${_sliderBox.className} img:nth-child(2)`), 50 , function () {
        console.log('fadeOut done');
    });
```

```css
.fadeSlider{
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
            box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px gray;
        }
        .fadeSlider img{
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div class="fadeSlider">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 2 example for u.
I recommend example 1 for learning promises

```js
/* example 1 */
function fadeOutEffect(fadeTarget, interval) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    let fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
      if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity){
        fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
      }
      if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0){
        fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.05;
      } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect);
        resolve();
      }
    }, interval)
  })
}

fadeOutEffect(document.querySelector( `.${_sliderBox.className} img:nth-child(2)`), 50).then(()=>{
  console.log('fadeOut done');
});

/* example 2 */
function fadeOutEffect(fadeTarget, interval,callback) { // add callback as parameter
    let fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
      if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity){
        fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
      }
      if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0){
        fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.05;
      } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect);
        callback() // run callback
      }
    }, interval)
}

fadeOutEffect(document.querySelector( `.${_sliderBox.className} img:nth-child(2)`), 50,()=>{
  console.log('fadeOut done');
});
```

Comment: I'll use the first example to learn promises, thank you for your time and helpful answers!

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the callback parameter in the `fadeOutEffect` function and call the callback after `clearInterval(fadeEffect)`.

```
let _sliderBox = document.getElementsByClassName('fadeSlider')[0];
    let img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF';
    _sliderBox.appendChild(img1);
    let img2 = new Image();
    img2.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/300/FF0000';
    _sliderBox.appendChild(img2);
    // pass the callback as a parameter for fadeOutEffect
    function fadeOutEffect(fadeTarget, interval, callback) {
        let fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
            if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity){
                fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
            }
            if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0){
                fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.05;
            } else {
                clearInterval(fadeEffect);
                callback()  // call the callback here
            }
           
        }, interval)
        
    }
    fadeOutEffect(document.querySelector( `.${_sliderBox.className} img:nth-child(2)`), 50 , function () {
        console.log('fadeOut done');
    });
```

You can name the `callback` perimeter whatever you think would be more appropriate for your code. I named it `callback` to make it easier for you to see my modifications.